# How to create responsive design in android for any screen?

Tags: android

How can I size my application to fit all screens? ( from nexus 4 to nexus 6p)
I have created a folder layout-normal but it contains 3 phones, but I wanted something more specific.
Please help me.

Comment: There are *thousands* of Android device models, with dozens, if not hundreds, of different screen size/resolution combinations. Attempting to implement a different design for each device is akin to having a different Web design for each possible browser window size (800x600,801x600,800x601,...). You need to come up with a more fluid design, one that can work across small variations in size (e.g., 4" to 6" diagonal). Implement different designs for different major form factors (e.g., phones/phablets, larger tablets, TVs desktops).

Answer (score 0):

The better way to support all different sizes is multiple layouts...

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/practices/screens_support.html

All documentation help you about this. In text sometimes is better user small, Medium or High and not a sp.

But read the documentation and use [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can provide multiple resolutions for different resources, using different 'drawable' images, as shown at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

More information at this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3263288/5127934